# How to query SharePoint items that contain one or more text values CAML?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, caml-query, jsom, caml

I want to query for SharePoint items that contain at least one or more specified texts. For example, I have a field called "Pets." A SharePoint item would have a value that looks something like "Cat, Snake, Spider" or "Bear, Rat." So the number of pets will vary. If I want to only query for items that contain the words "Cat," "Dog," or "Frog," how would I do that using CAML query? The number of words I'll be checking for will be dynamic.

I tried this:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Pets' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Cat</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
             <FieldRef Name='Pets' />
             <Value Type='Text'>Dog</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Pets' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Frog</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Or** construct like:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
        <Or>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Pets' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Cat</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
             <FieldRef Name='Pets' />
             <Value Type='Text'>Dog</Value>
        </Contains>
        </Or>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Pets' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Frog</Value>
        </Contains>
         </Or>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This would only work if I'm looking for 3 words though right? I'm looking for something that's dynamic. For example, I would be checking if the field contains at least one of the 3, 4, or even 10 words I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, it will return all items that contain these values for field [Pets]. If you would like to add more words, you just need to add more <Or>  conditions. Let me know.. or post a sample that you would like to see.